# how to retrieve json response objects which stores values inside nested arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I've json object with key named geometry,the geometry key stores array called path & the path stores multidimensional array

I tried to loop through paths but loops returns only the first index values

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
foreach($JsonData->features as $chunk )
{
    $geo =$chunk->geometry->paths;
    echo $geo;
}
```

expected result - is to store the paths values into one variable.
actual result - returning only one value.

The data is...

```
"geometry": { "paths": [ [ [ -9131174.97888261, 3120622.68129019 ], 
    [ -9131167.41739487, 3120625.21649344 ], 
    [ -9131007.49336538, 3120782.33590721 ], 
    [ -9130998.82313552, 3120791.07506482 ] ] ] }
```

Comment: "geometry": {
        "paths": [
          [
            [
              -9131174.97888261,
              3120622.68129019
            ],
            [
              -9131167.41739487,
              3120625.21649344
            ],
            [
              -9131007.49336538,
              3120782.33590721
            ],
            [
              -9130998.82313552,
              3120791.07506482
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
this how the data is

Answer (score 0):

The following code should get you back on track:

```
<?php
$json = '{ "paths": [ [ [ -9131174.97888261, 3120622.68129019 ], [ -9131167.41739487, 3120625.21649344 ], [ -9131007.49336538, 3120782.33590721 ], [ -9130998.82313552, 3120791.07506482 ] ] ] }';
$object = json_decode($json);

foreach($object->paths[0] as $path) {
    $geo = $path;
    echo $geo[0];
    echo $geo[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you keep on overwriting the value in `$geo` you will only get 1 value.  You should build an array (adding each value using `[]`) and that should give you all of the results.  You may also need to adjust the way you access the data, I've updated the loop to `$JsonData->features->geometry->paths[0]`...

```
$geo = [];
foreach($JsonData->features->geometry->paths[0] as $chunk )
{
    $geo[] =$chunk;
}
print_r($geo);
```

which results in something like...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => -9131174.9788826
            [1] => 3120622.6812902
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => -9131167.4173949
            [1] => 3120625.2164934
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => -9131007.4933654
            [1] => 3120782.3359072
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => -9130998.8231355
            [1] => 3120791.0750648
        )

)
```

Comment: ok i got the data as the above format,now i've insert data into database

Comment: when i use $geo variable into insert query,throwing error Array to string conversion

Comment: You can't just insert it in one go, does your table have latitude and longitude as separate fields?  You may have to loop over `$geo` and insert them one at a time.

Comment: its doesn't have longitude or latitude but has it has column named shapes with datatype of geometry.this data is shape file format

Comment: i'm looping like this
    foreach($chunk->geometry->paths[0] as $geometry )
    {
        $geo =$geometry;
        // echo '<pre>'.$geo[0].'</pre>';
        // echo '<pre>'.$geo[1].'</pre>';

        $geo1=$geo[0];
        $geo1.=','.$geo[1];

        
    }

Comment: Does `$geo[0]` echo out as the value your after?

Comment: yeah,but i'm unable to store the values in geometry datatype column

Comment: You don't show the code which does this, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/28917183/1213708 which may help.  It may be easier to open a new question which shows your current code and how you try and insert the data and what isn't working.